# How to Convert HTML/CSS to PDF in PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have been trying to convert an html page to PDF with out any luck, I have tried to use wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and the PHP class provided by the same developers (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp) although the following command executed correctly in terminal:

```
wkhtmltopdf http:/www.googl.com test.pdf
```

I was unable to execute the command in PHP because of the following error:
cannot connect to X server.

Can any one provide me with a step-by-step tutorial in order to be able to convert html/css to PDF file, whether using wkhtmltopdf or any other decent solution.

Thanks in advance

here is the class that i have used http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

and below is my code

```
$html = file_get_contents("test.html");

$pdf = new WKPDF();

$pdf->set_html($html);

$pdf->render();

$pdf->output(WKPDF::$PDF_EMBEDDED,'sample.pdf');
```

Below is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'WKPDF didn't return any data.
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available
(required by /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0) No protocol specified wkhtmltopdf: cannot
connect to X server :0 </pre>' in /var/www/c4/components/com_wkhtmltopdf
/wkhtmltopdf.class.php:211 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/c4/components/com_wkhtmltopdf
/wkhtmltopdf.php(68): WKPDF->render() #1 /var/www/c4/components/com_wkhtmltopdf
/wkhtmltopdf.php(50): html2pdf() #2 /var/www/c4/index2.php(114): require_once('/var/ww...') 
#3 {main} thrown in /var/www/c4/components/com_wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.class.php on line 211
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php
And try the search function. ;)

Comment: As you're asking that broad and you're TIA type of guy: Please use the duplicate, K THX TIA! - Go through the answers there step by step.

Comment: Paul, the thread that you have sent is the same thread that lead me to wkhmltopdf library, and after trying the steps above i decided to ask for help

Comment: Please post the code (PHP) you have tried.  We can't help without seeing your code.  Incidentally, the "cannot connect to X server" error may be because the user running the PHP script does not have permission to do so.  What is your environment?  Is X even running, or is this a headless server that you connect to remotely?  Is this hosted, or in-house (ie, do you have complete control over the box)?

Comment: daiscog: i have added the code and yes i do have full control over the server. thanks

Comment: You have two errors in `http:/www.googl.com` - it's missing a forward slash and the 'e'!

Comment: This question is far too broad, and requires more research, imo. See the questions in _Related_ to see how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, The following error "No protocol specified wkhtmltopdf: cannot
connect to X server :0" was basically caused by on old version of "wkhtmltopdf" which was installed using apt-get. The solution was to download the static binary from the code.google using the following link: 
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

and then perform the following actions:

```
tar -jxvf wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0-static.tar.bz2
sudo aptitude install ia32-libs
```

Next, you’ll have to make a symbolic link pointing to WKHTMLTOPDF in /usr/bin.

```
sudo ln -s /full_path/WKHTMLTOPDF /usr/bin/WKHTMLTOPDF
```